# Find basis which fits quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $g(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ for some real $a,b,c$.

Find a basis (or show one exists) $\{v_1,v_2\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $g(xv_1+yv_2)=gx^2+hy^2$ where $g,h=\pm 1$ or $0$.

A hint would be appreciated. Am I allowed to choose $a,b,c$? I know I can write this as a quadratic form using a matrix, but I don't see how that would help. How do I get the middle term $bxy$ to vanish by choosing a fixed basis?

Comment: Find a symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $g(x,y) = z^TAz$, where $z = (x,y)^T$. Then find a unitary $U$ and a diagonal $D$ such that $A = U^TDU$. Then $g(z) = v^TDv$, where $v = Uz$, hence $g(U^Tv) = v^TDv = d_1v_1^2 + d_2v_2^2$. Then you are close.

Comment: Can you explain how I go about finding A? Should it relate to the constants $a,b,c$? Or $g,h$?

Comment: $g$ is given in terms of $a,b,c$. So of course $A$ should involve $a,b,c$. Start by setting $A = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\beta&\gamma\end{pmatrix}$ and find $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ in terms of $a,b,c$.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Can you explain a bit about ho to find the unitary matrix?

Comment: Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$. It is better to do that with the $A$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ first. Then put the two eigenvectors into $U^T$ and the eigenvalues into $D$.

Comment: Oh, I think I can see now. Once I have the eigenvalue decomposition, I can normalize to ensure that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are $\pm 1$ or $0$? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly correct. And the basis that you have to find is a basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Great, thank you. If at some point you'd like to combine your comments into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) First, let $A = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\beta&\gamma\end{pmatrix}$ be an arbitrary symmetric matrix. Find its eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}$ and corresponding eigenvectors $u_{1,2}$. Then you have $A = UDU^T$ with $U = [u_1,u_2]$ and $D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, everything in terms of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. The matrix $U$ will be unitary.

(2) Then find a symmetric(!) matrix $A$ such that $g(x,y) = z^TAz$, where $z = (x,y)^T$. In the first step you have calculated the decomposition $A = UDU^T$ already. Thus, you have
$$
g(z) = z^TAz = z^TUDU^Tz = w^TDw,
$$
where $w = U^Tz$. As $z = Uw$, this gives
$$
g(w_1u_1 + w_2u_2) = g(Uw) = w^TDw = d_1w_1^2 + d_2w_2^2.
$$
That's almost what was asked for. You are only left with scaling everything appropriately.